# Perforce: File tampered with after resolve - edit or revert

Tags: perforce

I'm doing an integration in Perforce and am being met with the following:

```
p4 integrate -1 -d -i -t -r -b my_branchspec
//Foo/file.txt#6 - integrate from //Bar/file.txt#6
p4 resolve -am
/Foo/file.txt - merging //Bar/file.txt#6
/Foo/file.txt tampered with before resolve - edit or revert.
```

It seems no matter what I do, I am unable to make this issue go away: the next forward integration will show a similar message.

The file is a text file. I can confirm that the MD5 hash for both files *before* the integration takes place is the same. What other issues might be going on with this file that I can resolve to fix this nagging message?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Doing a forced resync (`sync -f`) of that particular file and then resolving theirs (`resolve -at`) (since I did not touch the file) makes the issue go away.

Answer (score 1):

By any chance are you working in a mixed OS environment, in particular Mac and PC?

We are currently investigating an issue where files are disappearing after resolve (without an error!) on a pc. The file type is "apple" (but shouldn't have been/doesn't need to be. Unfortunately we have a lot of these files already in the depot).

The current workaround is to do the integrations on a mac.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what caused this - maybe the permissions on the file were changed ?

In any case, if you revert //Foo/file.txt you should be OK.

Comment: If you've forgotten to reconcile a local edit - the most common reason for the message - reverting the file will mean you ***permanently lose*** your local edits.  Best make a backup of the local file before doing this, then diff against the backup to see if it's a change you want to keep.

Answer (score 0):

You may encounter this issue if when trying to merge changes you give up on the merge tool and instead use an external editor to apply the changes.

I do not know how to get rid of the error, so that it will just accept my manual "tampering".

What does seem to work (and which is a slight PITA) is

- Take a copy of the entire source tree;
- Revert all changes in P4V;
- Diff that with the copy and re-apply all changes to the P4V workspace tree;
- In P4V, select 'Reconcile Offline Work';
- Commit the changes;
- Re-attempt the merge of the changesets required;
- Resolve all conlicts by selecting "accept target";
- Commit the unchanged files.

The final steps are required so that P4V knows the changesets have been merged.

I hope someone from Perforce reads this.  Not having an option via the GUI to override the "tampering" error is a total PITA.